# Scalability of Views in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, button, screen, scalability

I am unable to make scalable views, based on the reading till I got these ways to scale views :

- To Change Layouts for different screen size (xhdpi etc.)
- To use dp in sizes and sps in fonts
- To dynamically change sizes of Views using Java code
- To use Relative Layout properties

I found most suitable using dp and sps but that's not working accurately, i.e. on devices with scale 3.0 it does not actually works as the screen sizes are probably different that from the standard screen sizes (for which scale is calculated).

Hence I am confused how to make a scalable UI.

I am currently designing a calculator app, hence a grid of 4 buttons (row) and 5 columns has to be created but the arrangement is taking load on me, i.e.

Answer (score 0):

Using LinearLayout with width 0dp and weight 1 for each child can solve your problem. It assures that whatever be the screen size, area for each child will be distributed according to the given weight. See if it helps.